# Probability of $m_l=1$ if $l=1$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

I am solving a problem asked to find $\left\langle\hat{L}_z\right\rangle$ given that $l=1$, $s=1/2$, $j=1/2$, and $m_j=1/2$. My approach is to solve it by $$\left\langle\hat{L}_z\right\rangle = \left\langle lm_l\left\vert\hat{L}_z\right|lm_l\right\rangle$$
but $m_l$ is not given.

To do this one must know what $m_l$ is of course, which can take values $-l,-l+1,\ldots,l$, but the problem does not give this information and I do not think it is something that can be computed.

**However, the explanations up until this point were just context as to why I am asking my question, which is:**

> If we know that the azimuthal quantum number of our system is $l=1$, but I do not know what the magnetic quantum number is exactly, would we be able to say that there is a 33% chance that $m_l=1$? Since $m_l$ can only be one of the following three numbers: $-1, 0, 1$.

Comment: Do you know about Clebsch-Gordan coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $j$ and $m_j$ are the quantum numbers associated with the total angular momentum $\hat{\vec{L}}+\hat{\vec{S}}$. Consider the eigenstate
$$
\lvert j,m_j;l,s \rangle = \lvert 1/2,1/2;1,1/2 \rangle
$$
of the operators $\hat{J}^2$, $\hat{J}_z$, $\hat{L}^2$, and $\hat{S}^2$. Using Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, we can expand this state in the product basis
$$
\lvert l,m_l\rangle\lvert s,m_s \rangle
$$
of eigenstates of $\hat{L}^2$, $\hat{L}_z$, $\hat{S}^2$, and $\hat{S}_z$. The relevant Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are shown below, from which we discern that
$$
\lvert 1/2,1/2;1,1/2 \rangle =
\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\lvert 1,1\rangle\lvert 1/2,-1/2 \rangle
-
\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\lvert 1,0\rangle\lvert 1/2,1/2 \rangle
$$.
From here, a straight-forward calculation shows that
$$
\langle \hat{L}_z \rangle = \frac{2\hbar}{3}\,.
$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have given not the product state ($|l,m_l\rangle \otimes |s,m_s\rangle$) but total angular momentum ket ($|j,m\rangle) $. You can use the [Clebsc-Gordan coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) to write these in terms of product state. You can find the table for [CG coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) here. Once you find the state in term of product state, the rest is quite trivial.